# Is there a good alternative to using Microsoft.Identity scaffolding?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I needed a quick web application users handling in my Blazor project. So I went with `Microsoft.Identity` and the scaffolding feature in Visual Studio.

However, at least in VS 2019 it doesn't work perfectly. It does require many manual tweaks, the code produced is ugly to my taste, it leaves a lot of "foreign" code in my project.

I have no easy way to customize its style and behavior to my application without editing a lot of files. CSS is not enough. A simple example: I wanted my users to be logged by their user name, not the e-mail, however the e-mail is required by registration. What's more, the user name is the primary key in the `User` entity since I needed it while importing the previous company database. I wanted the forms to be localized. I already made it, but is there a simpler way?

Do you know a library or a NuGet package to make this task easier and quicker? It would be nice if it supported various log on methods, like logging via Azure or Google or a kind of 2FA.

The requirement is my User entity is completely custom. Its primary key can be an `int`, a `Guid` or a `string`. Many optional properties, depending on the application. `Microsoft.Identity` satisfies all the requirements related to the backend, but it doesn't have a "proper" front end for Blazor. The scaffolding feature of VS provides a makeshift UI, but it's far from being the "real solution".

I wonder if not write such library myself, but it would be a huge waste of time if such thing is already available somewhere and I just don't know about it.

Comment: It is difficult to find an existing package to meet your requirements, because this kind of package is a general template or solution, if you want to privatize it and add your personal profile, you have to change the template and do some customization.

Comment: So, I think I'm going to go my way and try to make the impossible: a code to generate forms as independent from HTML layout and frameworks used as it gets. I suspect that generating the most basic and "by the book" pure HTML forms would play nicely with any CSS framework and layout. And generating forms instead of using templates would achieve full separation between backend details and the frontend.